# NHibernate to generate SQL scripts file

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Is possible use NHibernate to generate a SQL script file?

If not, there is any lib that I can use with NH to generate it instead of I commit the changes?

Comment: A script of what? Are you asking if NH can output a schema for your mappings? Or are you asking if NH queries can be output to a file?

Comment: I want to output NH queries into a file

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate does not out support exporting of SQL commands, but you can tweak the it's logging to log [sql along with the](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249154/Logging-NHibernate-queries-with-parameters) parameters, please refer.